# Jquery Collapsing Category

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently try to make a collapsible category list using html table tag and jquery.

This is my jquery :

```
  (function() {
    var toggle = $('span.toggle');
    toggle.on('click', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var objectClass = $this.parent().parent().attr('class');
      toggleRow($this, objectClass);
    });

    function toggleRow(element, elClass) {
      var classes = elClass.split(' ');
      var textList = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (classes[i].length > 0) {
          textList += "."+classes[i];
        }
      }
      var $this = element.parents(textList);
      var lastRow = $this.index() == $('tr' + textList).last().index() ? true : false;
      if($this.attr('data-collapse') !== 'collapsed') {

        if(!lastRow) {
          $this.attr('data-collapse', 'collapsed').nextUntil('tr' + textList).hide();
        } else {
          $this.attr('data-collapse', 'collapsed').nextUntil('tr.has-children').hide();
        }
      } else {
        if(!lastRow) {
          $this.attr('data-collapse', '').nextUntil('tr' + textList).show();
        } else {
          $this.attr('data-collapse', '').nextUntil('tr.has-children').show();
        }
      }
    }
  }());
```

this is my HTML :

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="MainMenu">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="50">No</th>
      <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parent-row has-children" data-collapse="">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <span class="toggle"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></span>Dog
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row" data-collapse="">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <span class="toggle"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></span>Foods and Treats
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-child-row">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        Dry Food
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent-row has-children" data-collapse="">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <span class="toggle"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></span>Dog
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row" data-collapse="">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <span class="toggle"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></span>Foods and Treats
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-child-row">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        Dry Food
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the problem is when i click tr tag with "child-row" class, the jquery collapse UNTIL THE NEXT tr tag WITH "child-row" CLASS !
so if there is tr tag with "parent-row" class between 2 tr tag with class "child-row", its also closed.

I found the problem in my Jquery but i cannot fixed it, it was in this row :

```
var lastRow = $this.index() == $('tr' + textList).last().index() ? true : false;
```

it will always return false, except for the LAST tr tag WITH CLASS "child-row" in the table

I know my explanation is kinda blur, i make a fiddle here :
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelAng/2gLr3a6q/)

but i'm also kinda new to JsFiddle, i even cannot make my code work there.
So, i someone knew how to fix this code, please reply. Thanks.

Comment: you can try to take a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/7ty3b/

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but your example is 2-level list type, while I have 3-level. Closing between the level 2 and level 3 is the problem. thanks anyway.